# Cant shift to the next cell In specific column

Tags: google-sheets

I want to save my pivot cell, and every time user press a button , it will shift to the next cell. i mean to the ID of the cell e.g D9, D10 D11, etc.
and not to the value of the cell

```
sheetDB.getRange("D9").setValue((pivot + 1)
```

i have tried to increase it by 1 but then i get in first run cell: D9 and then after the user press the button,the cell become: D91
but its wrong (for me)

Comment: google script support regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Background to your problem**

The `pivot` was a text "1", and the operation you do is concatenating strings:

"9" + 1 = "91"

You need to get the string "9" and convert "9" to a number:

`+pivot + 1`

Here's a test:

```
function test_sum_string()
{
  var str = "9";
  Logger.log(str + 1); // 91
  Logger.log(+str + 1);  // 10
}
```

Since you have 'D9', the regax is:

`/\d+$/.exec("D9")[0]` // will give text "9"

**Sample Function**

```
function getNextCell(CellA1Notation)
{
  var result = /([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)$/.exec(CellA1Notation);  
  return result[1] + (+result[2] + 1);  
}
```

Alternative:

```
function getNextCell2(CellA1Notation)
{
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(CellA1Notation).offset(1, 0).getA1Notation();
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks! One more thing, can you modifey the regex expression as it will "throw away' any char and will leave numbers only? As if i will want to change the column (instead of D it will be E,F,G etc.) in the future. BTW, how do i add the char (in this case, the letter 'D') again after increasing the index number by one?

Comment: @user1284567, your welcome! Just realized, there's a native solution. Please see the edit.